# Can a 7 year cocker spaniel be house trained easy

Tags: toilet-training

I'm thinking of adopting a 7 year old cocker spaniel. Can he be easily house trained

Comment: Do you know that he isn't?

Comment: This question can't easily have a yes or no answer. It really depends on the previous environment the cocker spaniel was in. If he was previously house trained, it may just be an issue of marking his territory a few times and then it stops. However, if he came from an abusive household, this could open up a new can of worms. There could be an issue of separation anxiety, peeing when scared (which could be very frequent). I think you need to clarify your question more with where the spaniel is coming from before you can get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to popular belief, old dogs can learn new tricks...

Assuming there are no underlying issues you may not be aware of (talk to your vet), I would say, yes.

1. It takes **patience** and **consistency**.
2. If your dog is food driven, get yourself some training treats. Yes, "training treats".

Take the dog outside to potty every couple of hours and try to keep a routine every day. Take them to the same spot **every time**. If going for a walk, take them on the same route every time. Do this for a month or two. It would be a good idea to continue for a while, even after they have learned where you want them to go.

Use praise ("good boy/girl!") when they do go potty outside and give treats directly after they have finished. Get used to putting them in your pockets or get a treat bag from the pet store to carry them in. Do this *every time*.

**Do not** scold or punish the dog for going inside because they may learn to fear going in front of you, which will make training them even harder. If you catch them in the act, say a quick "no!" and take them directly out, even if they have already finished.